# Symfony FOSUserBundle login_check returning ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have configured FOSUserBundle in Symfony. The code works properly on linux machine. But when I copy the code on to macosx LAMP setup (including the vendor folder), the login doesnt work. Any attempt to login throws ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on login_check . Inspecting the network calls also shows nothing, developer inspector simply shows failed.

Interestingly, if I copy the code to another linux machine, it work. But copying to macosx, login fails.

The configuration in linux and macosx is identical. Symfony version 3.3 .

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Reason for down vote? This is a genuine problem I am facing...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a server issue.
Try changing the PHP version if possible on MacOS X or completely reinstalling the local server.